# How to cancel volly request in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity which contain Listview when user scrolldown a request is sent to server for more data Request is sent by parameter count=5(it is always static) and last=5 and again on scroll down last becomes 10 and what I want when server response is "No item" then I want to cancel volley requeston listview scroll down.How can I do that

code for Listview scroll down;

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && bBottomOfView) {
        Log.i("Listview", "scrolling stopped...");
        if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
            m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
            m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

            sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
            sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
            Log.e(TAG, "Last Count::" + sz_LastCount);
            Log.e(TAG, "Record count::" + sz_RecordCount);


            loadmoreData();


        } else {
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Please check internet connection !", getActivity());
            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
        }

    }
}
```

and code for load more data

```
public void loadmoreData() {

    try {
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        Log.d("CAppList:", sz_RecordCount);
        Log.d("Capplist:", sz_LastCount);
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to  string
        Log.i(TAG, "Server Request:-" + json);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        final String m_DealListingURL = "http://202.131.144.1:8080/json/metallica/getDealListInJSON";

        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, m_DealListingURL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:-" + response);
                try {
                    int nResultCodeFromServer = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("resultcode"));
                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_TRANSACTION_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// GETTING DEAL LIST
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// GETTING DEAL AT POSITION AT I
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// object create of DealAppdatastorage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));//getting deal name
                            item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// getting deal code
                            item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));

                            if (!s_oDataset.contains(item)) {
                                s_oDataset.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                        m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kCONNECTION_LOST) {//server based conditions
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kDEAL_NOT_FOUND) {// serevr based conditions .....
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

                        if (m_ListView.getFooterViewsCount() != 0) {
                            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
                        }

                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kTECHNICAL_FAILURE) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Technical Failure", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kALREADY_AVAIL_BENEFIT) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "You have already avail the benefit of this deal", getActivity());
                    } else if (nResultCodeFromServer == m_kTIMED_OUT) {
                        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Timed Out", getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println("Error:-" + error);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection lost ! Please try again", getActivity());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No internet connection", getActivity());
                }
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cancel request like below

You have to add tag to every request so you can cancel all the request for particular tag.

```
public static final String TAG = "MyTag";
StringRequest stringRequest; // Assume this exists.
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;  // Assume this exists.

// Set the tag on the request.
stringRequest.setTag(TAG);

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
mRequestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Cancel

**`mRequestQueue.cancelAll(TAG);`**

### See this [How to cancel volley request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html#cancel)